# Make excel vba insert custom number of rows of data between rows based on custom criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure how to explain this question, but I will try my best to explain the logic of what I need to be done. Hopefully any of the brilliant guys at this website could throw in some ideas :)

I have log of data that contains information about different projects. Every row contains information of a project such as project name, date project created, date project finished, estimated date of project completion, and a timestamp of when an estimate was inserted/updates.  If a project has an updated estimated date of project completion, then this update is recorded in a new row.  This is how the data should look like in excel.

[image]

I need excel to check if any day passes with no change in the estimated completion date (i.e the project stays on track), then excel creates rows until it reaches a day that contains an update. The picture below shows how i need excel to add the custom rows based on the initial rows above.

[image]

Please let help me out with any ideas .. VBA is recommended.

Comment: Consider showing what you have tried so far, it goes a long way in making it look like you're not simply asking other people to do your job for you...  If you *literally* do not know where to start, read up on `Do/While` and `For/Next` loops.

Comment: @DavidZemens thank you ! I tried to do it on excel formulas but seems there isn't an easy solution to it...  I will give it a shot on vba... Also, I am not asking anyone to do my job for me, but I am throwing my question out there in case someone encountered the similar puzzle and i will do the rest plus i don't have to reinvent the wheel if someone else did it already sort of thing.....

Comment: Definitely can't be done with formulas since they can't manipulate the sheet/rows.

Comment: +1 @DavidZemens. The only way to use formulas would be to have a the second list, with extra rows, on a second sheet and use array formulas. Even still, it's far better suited for VBA.

Comment: @NickPeranzi Thanks problem solved

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! If the solution worked for you, please consider marking my answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should accomplish your goals:

```
Sub FillCompletionDays()

Dim LLoop As Long
Dim LLRow As Long
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim DateNext As Date
Dim DateNow As Date

LLoop = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Project name").Row + 1
LLRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If LLRow <= LLoop Then Exit Sub

Do
    'Only proceed if there is a valid date in column E
    If Range("E" & LLoop).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        DateNow = Range("E" & LLoop).Value2
        DateEnd = Range("C" & LLoop).Value2
        'Check if another date is needed
        If DateEnd > DateNow Then
            'Check if next row is this project
            If Range("A" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop).Value2 Then
                'Check if a new date is needed
                DateNext = DateSerial(Year(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2), Month(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2), _
                Day(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2))
                If DateNext <> DateNow + 1 Then
                    'Insert a row
                    Rows(LLoop + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    Range("A" & LLoop + 1 & ":D" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop & ":D" & LLoop).Value2
                    Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = DateNow + 1
                    Range("B" & LLoop + 1 & ": E" & LLoop + 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                    LLRow = LLRow + 1
                End If

            Else
                'Next row is another project; insert a row for this one
                Rows(LLoop + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                Range("A" & LLoop + 1 & ":D" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop & ":D" & LLoop).Value2
                Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = DateNow + 1
                Range("B" & LLoop + 1 & ": E" & LLoop + 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                LLRow = LLRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
    LLoop = LLoop + 1
Loop Until LLoop > LLRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.. Your code was helpful ! I have updated your code to fit my needs and how I wanted it to function !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question after editing @Nick Peranzi answer to fit my request I don't know how to tag/mention him but that's his user link 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5472502/nick-peranzi

```
Sub FillCompletionDays()

Dim LLoop As Long
Dim LLRow As Long
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim DateNext As Date
Dim DateNow As Date

LLoop = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Project name").Row + 1
LLRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If LLRow <= LLoop Then Exit Sub

Do
'Only proceed if there is a valid date in column E
If Range("E" & LLoop).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
    DateNow = DateSerial(Year(Range("E" & LLoop).Value2), Month(Range("E" & LLoop).Value2), _
            Day(Range("E" & LLoop).Value2))
    DateEnd = DateSerial(Year(Range("D" & LLoop).Value2), Month(Range("D" & LLoop).Value2), _
            Day(Range("D" & LLoop).Value2))
    'Check if another date is needed
    If DateEnd > DateNow Then
        'Check if next row is this project
        If Range("A" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop).Value2 Then
            'Check if a new date is needed
            DateNext = DateSerial(Year(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2), Month(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2), _
            Day(Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2))
            If DateNext = DateNow Then
            Else
            If DateNext <> DateNow + 1 Then
                'Insert a row
                Rows(LLoop + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                Range("A" & LLoop + 1 & ":D" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop & ":D" & LLoop).Value2
                Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = DateNow + 1
                Range("B" & LLoop + 1 & ": E" & LLoop + 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                LLRow = LLRow + 1
            End If
            End If

        Else
            'Next row is another project; insert a row for this one
            Rows(LLoop + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
            Range("A" & LLoop + 1 & ":D" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = Range("A" & LLoop & ":D" & LLoop).Value2
            Range("E" & LLoop + 1).Value2 = DateNow + 1
            Range("B" & LLoop + 1 & ": E" & LLoop + 1).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
            LLRow = LLRow + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
LLoop = LLoop + 1
Loop Until LLoop > LLRow


End Sub
```